# JACK/Pulseaudio: Output audio from JACK source to headphones (how to route different audio to different soundcards)

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, jack, usb-audio

I want to play a metronome audio tick out of the built-in headphone port, while playing an audio stream out of a USB soundcard. How can I do this?

---

Deeper context:

JACK is running the USB soundcard, and Pulseaudio is probably the thing that is in charge of the built-in soundcard*.

My first thought is to use both JACK and Pulseaudio in tandem, using the JACK sink for pulseaudio input.
Routing the metronome to the Pulseaudio JACK source makes the JACK source appear in pavucontrol under the 'Input Devices' tab - the mixer shows it is receiving the metronome signal. But no matter what I do I can't get this to actually be output by pulseaudio at any point.

How can I send the signal from JACK source to the built-in headphone port while still using the USB soundcard?

---

(* Tested this by using the 'Test Sound' function in Linux Mint's Sound manager - plays a test tone happily out of the headphones, which suggests this should be possible!)

---

*Edit: fix typo*

Comment: You don't seem to be running Pulseaudio at all (you can check with `ps axu`) I suggest to remove the `pulseaudio` tag.

Comment: Good point - though originally I thought that it was a pulseaudio problem. Better to leave it in to be helpful to people in a similar situation or remove it for correctness?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it!

Solution: using the `alsa_out` module.

> To use them, you start JACK as normal. Then you start an instance of `alsa_in` or `alsa_out` for each additional device (and “direction”) that you want to use. `alsa_out` will create a set of ports representing the playback capabilities of the device, and `alsa_in` will represent the capture/recording capabilities

So:

1. `arecord --list-devices` to find name of built-in soundcard (hw:0,0)
2. `alsa_out -d hw:0,0` to create the alsa_out ports that now appear in jack
3. Connect up metronome to `alsa_out` port in JACK - now plays metronome out of headphone socket and any other audio desired out of USB soundcard!

http://www.jackaudio.org/faq/multiple_devices.html

Comment: When doing step 2, it prints `Capture open error: Device or resource busy` for me. What is occupying it?